# Core Data isn't saving anything, but not giving an error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to recreate the absolute simplest Core Data example I could find, and I've still managed to run into a problem. It seems the SQLite database is being created in line with my Entity, but no actual data is being added to it. Here's my .h file:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

- (IBAction) createDatabase;

@end
```

And here's my .m:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction) createDatabase
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *myMO = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Book" inManagedObjectContext: _managedObjectContext];

    [myMO setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 123] forKey: @"bookID"];
    [myMO setValue: @"Example book." forKey: @"book"];
    [myMO setValue: @"Example author." forKey: @"author"];
    [myMO setValue: @"Example category." forKey: @"category"];
    [myMO setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey: @"isLiked"];
    [myMO setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey: @"isDisliked"];
}

@end
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Xcode creates the .sqlite file in the Documents directory of the app when I launch it, but hitting the button to call `createDatabase` doesn't cause any of the text ("Example book."), etc. to be entered into the SQLite file at all.

Am I doing something wrong? This code is pretty much copied and pasted, so I really don't know what I've done wrong.

Comment: Did you ever call "save" on the NSManagedObjectContext?

Comment: `NSManagedObjectContext` acts as a scratchpad- just because something is added to it doesn't mean it's been written to the db. As borrrden implies, you probably need to call `save` or else otherwise arrange for the save to occur (e.g. by using notifications)

Comment: Where is the save statement? If you don't save your changes you should not be surprised that the new entity does not show up in the acutal SQLite DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant find any thing in your code that saves your changes. It should be something like

```
 if (![myMO save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
 }
```

Refer this link for more help

1. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html
2. http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started
3. https://blog.stackmob.com/2012/11/iphone-database-tutorial-part-1-learning-core-data/

Comment: It's called in `applicationWillTerminate` in the AppDelegate.

Comment: Though apparently it's not called. Calling it manually fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, I'm pushing the button, then quitting the app. So it should have created them when I hit the button, then saved them on hitting close. But, it didn't.

Comment: Why you need to Quit app ?

Comment: Because that's where the save code was supposed to be executed.

Comment: Not getting you, can you show me how `applicationWillTerminate` is called manually ?

Comment: It isn't called manually. It's exactly as the boilerplate CoreData code created it. It calls the saveContext method upon applicationWillTerminate. What I'm saying is that that didn't happen.

Comment: Oh, haha, Ok, It is written since if your app terminates, your context is saved, but that does not mean that your appwillterminate method is always called.

Comment: If somewhere your app is terminated, your work wont be lost if your app is terminated

Comment: If the method isn't called, how's that happen?

Comment: At that time if we have handled it our self, no hazard will occur